# Couchbase Python sdk 2.5.3 Installation

Tags: couchbase, libcouchbase

I had installed python sdk in build machine and copied all installed files in another couchbase node and tried to use sdk. I am getting below error for _libcouchbase.so

> from couchbase.user_constants import * 
>     File "/DG/activeRelease/lib/python_lib/couchbase/user_constants.py", line 21, in `<module>`
>       import couchbase._bootstrap
>     File "/DG/activeRelease/lib/python_lib/couchbase/_bootstrap.py", line 34, in `<module>`
>       import couchbase.exceptions as E
>     File "/DG/activeRelease/lib/python_lib/couchbase/exceptions.py", line 18, in `<module>`
>       import couchbase._libcouchbase as C 
>   ImportError: /DG/activeRelease/lib/python_lib/couchbase/_libcouchbase.so: **undefined symbol: lcbtrace_span_get_operation**

And I have used import as below:

```python
import sys
sys.path.append('/DG/activeRelease/lib/python_lib/')

from couchbase.bucket import Bucket
from couchbase.views.params import Query
from couchbase.exceptions import CouchbaseError
from couchbase.exceptions import NotFoundError
```

The same code works for couchbase python sdk 2.3.2